# Browser race conditions leading to blank or corrupt cookies?

Tags: php, cookies

Is it possible for a browser to occasionally blank out a cookie, especially if it hasn't finished writing the cookie before the page changes?

We happen to have a cookie that changes every request.

Lately we switched over so that cookies are written via an ajax request.

The code (which happens to be in PHP) looks like this:

```
Request
  Cookie: xyz ...
Response
  Ajax Request
    Cookie: xyz ...
  Ajax Response with Set-Cookie: xyz...
```

This happens with every page request, however it seems that occasionally we see the cookie being blanked out on the browser side.

Also is it possible with a cookie that changes every request for some chance of corruption?

Comment: set_cookie('name','value', $expiration, '/', $cookieDomain);